# COBOL issue - issue from a beginner , please guide

Tags: cobol

I want to acheive the below

a string of pic X(5) contains A1992 and is incremented to A9999 , after it reaches A9999 , the A should be replaced by B and the other characters should be reinitialized to 0000 ie B0000 , this should happen until Z9999 , is it possible somehow ?

or if you could show me how to increment A till Z that would be suffice

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do some manual character manipulation on this one.  There are several parts, first, you need to handle the simple addition of the numeric portion, then you need to handle the rollover of that to increment the alpha portion.

Data structures similar to this might be helpful:

```
01 Some-Work-Area.
  02 Odometer-Char-Vals      pic x(27) value 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.
  02 Odometer-Char occurs 27 pic x.
  02 Odo-Char-Ndx            pic s9(8) binary.

01 My-Odometer.
    88 End-Odometer-Value    value 'Z9999'.
  02 My-Odometer-X           pic X.
  02 My-Odometer-9           pic 9999.
    88 Carry-Is-True         value 9999.
```

This would be used with a simple perform loop like so:

```
Move 0 to My-Odometer-9
Move 1 to Odo-Char-Ndx
Move Odometer-Char-Vals (Odo-Char-Ndx) to My-Odometer-X

Perform until End-Odometer-Value
   Add 1 to My-Odometer-9
   Display My-Odometer
   If Carry-Is-True
      Move 0 to My-Odometer-9
      Add 1 to Odo-Char-Ndx
      Move Odometer-Char-Vals (Odo-Char-Ndx) to My-Odometer-X
   End-If
End-Perform
```

That is one way you could do it.

Please note, the code above took some shortcuts (aka skanky hacks) -- like putting a pad cell in the Odometer-Char array so I don't have to range check it.  You wouldn't want to use this for anything but examples and ideas.

Comment: Looks like your code starts each letter series at `?0001` where `?` is the next letter. The OP asked each letter sries to start at `?0000`. If `Display My-Odomoter` is moved before the `Add 1...` the printed series will begin with `?0000` but `Z9999` is never printed. Maybe re-think this one a bit more...

Comment: with few tweaks, this works! But the way the code was written is simple and sleek.. I like the way!

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do this with a nested perform loop.

Storage:

```
01  ws-counter-def
    03  ws-counter-def-alpha-list      pic x(27) value 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.
    03  ws-counter-def-num             pic 9(4) comp-3.

01  ws-counter redefines ws-counter-def
    03  ws-counter-alpha occurs 27 times indexed by counter-idx   pic x.
    03  ws-counter-num                 pic 9(4) comp-3.      

01  ws-variable                        
    03  ws-variable-alpha              pic X
    03  ws-variable-num                pic X(4).
```

Procedure:

```
Initialize counter-idx.
Move 1992 to ws-counter-num.

Perform varying counter-idx from 1 by 1 until counter-idx > 26
  move ws-counter-alpha(counter-idx) to ws-variable-alpha
  perform until ws-counter-num = 9999
        add 1 to ws-counter-
        move ws-counter-num to ws-variable-num.
        *do whatever it is you need to do to the pic X(5) value in ws-variable*
  end-perform
  move zeros to ws-counter-num
end-perform.
```

Comment: Two minor improvements: 1) Change the UNTIL pharse of the outer loop to: `...until counter-idx > 26` 2) Since `counter-idx` never changes within the inner loop, put `move ws-counter-alpha(counter-idx)...` immediately above the inner loop.

Comment: ooh yeah, both good ones. I've changed my post to include your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just can't help myself... How about this...

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                         
   PROGRAM-ID. EXAMPLE.                                             
   DATA DIVISION.                                                   
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         
   01.                                                              
       02 ALL-LETTERS  PIC X(26) VALUE 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.
       02 LETTERS REDEFINES ALL-LETTERS.                            
          03 LETTER    PIC X OCCURS 26 INDEXED BY I. 
   01  START-NUMBER    PIC 9(4).              
   01  COUNTER.                                                     
       02 COUNTER-LETTER    PIC X.                                  
       02 COUNTER-NUMBER    PIC 9(4).                                
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MOVE 1992 TO START-NUMBER                                              
       PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > LENGTH OF ALL-LETTERS                   
           MOVE LETTER (I) TO COUNTER-LETTER                        
           PERFORM TEST AFTER VARYING COUNTER-NUMBER FROM START-NUMBER BY 1 
                                UNTIL COUNTER-NUMBER = 9999         
              DISPLAY COUNTER - or whatever else you need to do with the counter...             
           END-PERFORM
           MOVE ZERO TO START-NUMBER                                              
       END-PERFORM                                                  
       GOBACK                  
       .
```

This will print all the "numbers" beginning with `A1992` through to `Z9999`.

Basically stole Marcus_33's code and twiked it a tiny bit more. If you feel so inclined please upvote his answer, not mine

Answer (score 0):

For lovers of obfuscated COBOL, here's the shortest (portable) version I can think of (assuming a compiler with Intrinsic Functions):

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. so.
DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 ws-counter value "A00".
   03 ws-alpha   pic x.
   03 ws-number  pic 99.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
1.
     Perform with test after until ws-counter > "Z99"
       Display ws-counter, " " with no advancing
       Add 1 To ws-number
          On size error
             Move zero to ws-number
             perform with test after until ws-alpha is alphabetic-upper or > "Z"
                 Move Function Char (Function Ord( ws-alpha ) + 1) to ws-alpha
             end-perform 
       End-add
    End-perform.
END PROGRAM so.
```

Tested on OpenVMS/COBOL. I shorten the value to X(3) since it's boring to watch run.  A non-portable version (if you are aware of the [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform) is to redefined the prefix as a `S9(4) COMP` and increment the low-order bits directly.  But that solution wouldn't be any shorter...

Comment: Your code is not portable. It assumes that CHAR(ORD(SOME-LETTER) + 1) gives the next letter in the alphabet. This may be true of the ASCII character set but is flat out wrong for some other character sets. For example: CHAR(ORD('I') + 1) is not 'J' in the EBCDIC character set.

Comment: @NealB: Thanks I missed the gap when scanning the EBCDIC chart.  The edit is (more) portable.